# tensorflow neural net with continuous / floating point output?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to create a simple neural net in tensorflow that learns some simple relationship between inputs and outputs (for example, y=-x) where the inputs and outputs are floating point values (meaning, no softmax used on the output).

I feel like this should be pretty easy to do, but I must be messing up somewhere.  Wondering if there are any tutorials or examples out there that do something similar.  I looked through the existing tensorflow tutorials and didn't see anything like this and looked through several other sources of tensorflow examples I found by googling, but didn't see what I was looking for.

Here's a trimmed down version of what I've been trying.  In this particular version, I've noticed that my weights and biases always seem to be stuck at zero.  Perhaps this is due to my single input and single output?

I've had good luck altering the mist example for various nefarious purposes, but everything I've gotten to work successfully used softmax on the output for categorization.  If I can figure out how to generate a raw floating point output from my neural net, there are several fun projects I'd like to do with it.

Anyone see what I'm missing?  Thanks in advance!
- J.

```
  # Trying to define the simplest possible neural net where the output layer of the neural net is a single
  # neuron with a "continuous" (a.k.a floating point) output.  I want the neural net to output a continuous
  # value based off one or more continuous inputs.  My real problem is more complex, but this is the simplest
  # representation of it for explaining my issue.  Even though I've oversimplified this to look like a simple
  # linear regression problem (y=m*x), I want to apply this to more complex neural nets.  But if I can't get
  # it working with this simple problem, then I won't get it working for anything more complex.

  import tensorflow as tf
  import random
  import numpy as np


  INPUT_DIMENSION  = 1
  OUTPUT_DIMENSION = 1
  TRAINING_RUNS    = 100
  BATCH_SIZE       = 10000
  VERF_SIZE        = 1


  # Generate two arrays, the first array being the inputs that need trained on, and the second array containing outputs.
  def generate_test_point():
    x = random.uniform(-8, 8)

    # To keep it simple, output is just -x.  
    out = -x

    return ( np.array([ x ]), np.array([ out ]) )

  # Generate a bunch of data points and then package them up in the array format needed by
  # tensorflow
  def generate_batch_data( num ):
     xs = []
     ys = []

     for i in range(num):
       x, y = generate_test_point()

       xs.append( x )
       ys.append( y )

     return (np.array(xs), np.array(ys) )

  # Define a single-layer neural net.  Originally based off the tensorflow mnist for beginners tutorial

  # Create a placeholder for our input variable
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, INPUT_DIMENSION])

  # Create variables for our neural net weights and bias
  W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([INPUT_DIMENSION, OUTPUT_DIMENSION]))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([OUTPUT_DIMENSION]))

  # Define the neural net.  Note that since I'm not trying to classify digits as in the tensorflow mnist
  # tutorial, I have removed the softmax op.  My expectation is that 'net' will return a floating point
  # value.
  net = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

  # Create a placeholder for the expected result during training
  expected = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OUTPUT_DIMENSION])

  # Same training as used in mnist example
  cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(expected*tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(net,1e-10,1.0)))
  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

  sess = tf.Session()

  init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
  sess.run(init)

  # Perform our training runs

  for i in range( TRAINING_RUNS ):
    print "trainin run: ", i,

    batch_inputs, batch_outputs = generate_batch_data( BATCH_SIZE )

    # I've found that my weights and bias values are always zero after training, and I'm not sure why.
    sess.run( train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_inputs, expected: batch_outputs})

    # Test our accuracy as we train...  I am defining my accuracy as the error between what I 
    # expected and the actual output of the neural net.
    #accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sub( expected, net))  
    accuracy = tf.sub( expected, net) # using just subtract since I made my verification size 1 for debug

    # Uncomment this to debug
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    batch_inputs, batch_outputs = generate_batch_data( VERF_SIZE )
    result = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_inputs, expected: batch_outputs})

    print "    progress: "
    print "      inputs: ", batch_inputs
    print "      outputs:", batch_outputs
    print "      actual: ", result
```

Comment: Have you gotten your continuous value network to work? I am also trying to get a continuous-value network working.

Comment: FYI: I recognize the training rate of 0.5 comes straight from google's MNIST tutorial, but it actually quite high. Either use a decaying train rate or much lower. It's not uncommon to start around 0.001 (or 10x either way from that) with real data of unknown spatial topology

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your loss should be the squared difference of output and true value:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(expected - net))
```

This way the network learns to optimize this loss and make the output closer to the real result. Cross entropy should only be used for output values between 0 and 1 i.e. for classification.

Comment: Usually you want the L2 loss to have a smooth gradient. Your loss (which should be with `tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(expected - net))` btw) will have a gradient of +-1 with respect to the output `expected`, which will make it harder to converge when approaching the minimum

Comment: tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(expected - net)) did improve things.  I'm at least not diverging to nan any longer.  

Why did the sum of squares approach diverge to nan, though?

Comment: I tried that.  I wonder if my batch size is just too high for sum-of-squares calculation?

Tangent question -- do inputs to neural nets need to be normalized to a 0.0 - 1.0 floating point range, or can they be left in a "raw input" range.  I saw some other behavior in some of my experiments that seemed to suggest normalization of input data improved my results.

Comment: Yes it is better to normalize the input data between -1 and 1. You can also normalize the output: for instance if the true output is between -8 and 8, you multiply the network output by 8

Comment: Would using `tf.reduce_sum` instead of `tf.reduce_mean` mean that if you can't compare the error term if you change the batch size you are using to train?

Comment: @MikeKhan very true, I’ve changed it. Also remember that increasing the learning rate linearly with the batch size is a good heuristic.

Comment: Hi @OlivierMoindrot, if target is 0.8, error is same if output is 0.7 or 0.9 right? Question is MSE proper loss function if target is and output is between -15.xxx +8.xxx lets say?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is interested, I got this example to work. Here's the code:

```
# Trying to define the simplest possible neural net where the output layer of the neural net is a single
# neuron with a "continuous" (a.k.a floating point) output.  I want the neural net to output a continuous
# value based off one or more continuous inputs.  My real problem is more complex, but this is the simplest
# representation of it for explaining my issue.  Even though I've oversimplified this to look like a simple
# linear regression problem (y=m*x), I want to apply this to more complex neural nets.  But if I can't get
# it working with this simple problem, then I won't get it working for anything more complex.

import tensorflow as tf
import random
import numpy as np

INPUT_DIMENSION = 1
OUTPUT_DIMENSION = 1
TRAINING_RUNS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 10000
VERF_SIZE = 1


# Generate two arrays, the first array being the inputs that need trained on, and the second array containing outputs.
def generate_test_point():
    x = random.uniform(-8, 8)

    # To keep it simple, output is just -x.
    out = -x

    return (np.array([x]), np.array([out]))


# Generate a bunch of data points and then package them up in the array format needed by
# tensorflow
def generate_batch_data(num):
    xs = []
    ys = []

    for i in range(num):
        x, y = generate_test_point()

        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)

    return (np.array(xs), np.array(ys))


# Define a single-layer neural net.  Originally based off the tensorflow mnist for beginners tutorial

# Create a placeholder for our input variable
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, INPUT_DIMENSION])

# Create variables for our neural net weights and bias
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([INPUT_DIMENSION, OUTPUT_DIMENSION]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([OUTPUT_DIMENSION]))

# Define the neural net.  Note that since I'm not trying to classify digits as in the tensorflow mnist
# tutorial, I have removed the softmax op.  My expectation is that 'net' will return a floating point
# value.
net = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

# Create a placeholder for the expected result during training
expected = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OUTPUT_DIMENSION])

# Same training as used in mnist example
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(expected - net))
# cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(expected*tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(net,1e-10,1.0)))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

# Perform our training runs

for i in range(TRAINING_RUNS):
    print("trainin run: ", i, )

    batch_inputs, batch_outputs = generate_batch_data(BATCH_SIZE)

    # I've found that my weights and bias values are always zero after training, and I'm not sure why.
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_inputs, expected: batch_outputs})

    # Test our accuracy as we train...  I am defining my accuracy as the error between what I
    # expected and the actual output of the neural net.
    # accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sub( expected, net))
    accuracy = tf.subtract(expected, net)  # using just subtract since I made my verification size 1 for debug
    # tf.subtract()
    # Uncomment this to debug
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    print("W=%f, b=%f" % (sess.run(W), sess.run(b)))

    batch_inputs, batch_outputs = generate_batch_data(VERF_SIZE)
    result = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_inputs, expected: batch_outputs})

    print("    progress: ")
    print("      inputs: ", batch_inputs)
    print("      outputs:", batch_outputs)
    print("      actual: ", result)
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the built in, easy way of constructing the NN, I used

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError().
```